# Binary number as quantum observable variable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I am currently reading [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0pshtcwz067d1ez/physrevlett.74.4091%20%281%29.pdf?dl=0) article about quantum computations on set of N two-state ions. There author associates ground state with number zero $|0>$ and excited state of ion with number $|1>$ and then says, that general state of the system is:
$$|x>=|x_0>|x_1>|x_2>...|x_{N-1}>$$
where $x_i$ is eigenvalue that equals digital value 0 or 1 for i-th ion qubit. So, as I understand, in general system will have state $|x>$ with measurable value:
$$x=\sum_0^{N-1}x_i\cdot 2^i$$
Is this really possible? Can really exist a observable with such artificial nature? So how universe really guess from what side I measure ion with 0-th power of two and where I measure ion with $(N-1)$th power of two? x value will depend obviously on this.

Comment: A normal (not quantum) computer also has registers of bits, and if you have N bits then the value represented by that register is $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} x_i 2^i$, just as you've written. This has absolutely nothing to do with quantum mechanics. In a normal computer, like in a quantum one, data is represented by the states of physical things. In a normal computer, the data may be represented by presence and absence of charge, which is a physically observable quantity.

Comment: thanks, you should post it like an answer and i'll approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal (not quantum) computer also has registers of bits, and if you have $N$ bits then the value represented by that register is
$$\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} x_i 2^i$$ just as you've written.
This has absolutely nothing to do with quantum mechanics.
In a normal computer, like in a quantum one, data is represented by the states of physical things.
In a normal computer, the data may be represented by presence and absence of charge, which is a physically observable quantity.